# Cluster rendering in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection with 20 items in it. Now I can render them all (that would be easy) but what I want is to cluster them in groups. In the normal way of rendering with this code

```
this.collection.each(function(model){
    this.view(model)
});
```

The outcome would be like this

```
<ul><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li></ul>
```

What I want to do is in this format.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
         <a>Item1</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I already have the code for grouping them so not really a thing to worry what i don't quite get is on how to render it to desired output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to give more info for a answer to this. It really depends on your grouping code and how you need to be able to handle the resulting output.

Depending on the templating module you're using you could do it all in one view with a smart template, but I'm more inclined to think you want at least another view for each of the list items. Whether this renders a view for each model or not I'm not sure with the info you've provided.